# Getting color mismatch while converting from NV12 raw data to H264 using FFMPEG

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec, libavformat

I am trying to convert NV12 raw data to H264 using hw encoder of FFMPEG.

to pass raw data to encoder I am passing AVFrame struct using below logic:

```
    uint8_t * buf;
    buf = (uint8_t *)dequeue();
    frame->data[0] = buf;
    frame->data[1] = buf + size;
    frame->data[2] = buf + size;
    frame->pts = frameCount;
    frameCount++;
```

but using this logic, I am getting, color mismatched H264 data,

Can someone tell me , How to pass buffer to AVFrame data?

Thanks in Advance,
Harshil

Comment: Please note that I am passing correct NV12 data in buf

Comment: A guess: should `frame->data[2] = buf + size` be `frame->data[2] = buf + 2*size`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I dont think it is buf + 2*size because, v plane is at buf + size location in NV12 format.

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried with your suggestion getting same issue, please give me other alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved color mismatch issue by passing correct linesize and data value of AVFrame struct.

Let's say NV12 has YYYYUVUV plane for 4x4 image, then in ffmpeg, we need to pass

linesize[0] = start location of y

linesize[1] = 4 because location of u started at 4
and we dont need to specify linesize[2] because uv are packed.

and also in case of data

data[0] = start location of y

data[1] = 4